# Toggle button to hide group of elements by class and display nextSibling in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Please check out my HTML markup:

```
<button class="btn">Toggle</button>   
<p class="para">This is a text</p>

<!-- when .btn[0] click then .para[0] will be display block but all other para[1],para[2],....,para[n] will be display none--> 


<button class="btn">Toggle</button>
<p class="para">This is a text</p>

<!--- .btn[1] only works for .para[1]-->


<button class="btn">Toggle</button>
<p class="para">This is a text</p>

<!--- .btn[2] only works for .para[2]-->
```

When `.btn[0]` gets clicked then `.para[0]` should be `display:block`, but all other `para[1]`, `para[2]` , ...., `para[n]` will be `display:none`.

How can I achieve this in JavaScript or JQuery (without adding unique id's)?

Comment: Oh, Then actually what you want?

Comment: Specify your question...

Comment: question is missing the question.

Comment: How strange.. I got this question in the review que. So I fixed the invalid edit, cleaned up the title and voted to leave the question open.. upon which I *failed the audit*...?! Yet now the question is back, clear, alive and kicking.. So I didn't fail the audit.. the audit failed me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can hide all the `.para` by default using css:

```
.para {
    display: none
}
```

and using below code to show the expected paragraph as well as hiding other paragraphs

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.para').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J6Hy9/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.para').hide();
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $('.para').hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```

See [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tv6kF/)

Comment: +1 because this will leave the content readable to users with javascript disabled.